# In native DOM, is there a way to combine two nodes forming a scope for query purpose?

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

I have a custom element , which contains an inner  containing  for the users to fill in their custom input fields. Outside the  I have defined some custom element related boilerplate  fields also belonging to the same form. something like this:

```
<my-magic-form>
    <input disabled name="entry_id"></input>
    <slot name="fields_toFill"></slot>
</my-magic-form>
```

Now every time I do some query to get all the form's , I have to run twice like this:

```
const input_field = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("input");
const slotted_input = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("slot[name='fields_toFill']").assignedNodes();
...
```

Is there a way to combine `input_field` with `slotted_input` so I can do operations all at once? In jQuery you have `.add` method you can chain, but in vanilla Javascript this seems to be completely missing?

Comment: First, this isn't really a "vanilla JavaScript" thing; you're talking about native DOM APIs which are *not* part of JavaScript the language. And no, the native APIs that return node lists don't have facilities to combine them or to perform bulk operations (other than the ability, in newer browsers, to explicitly use the various Array iteration operations like `.forEach()`, `.map()`, `.reduce()`, etc).

Comment: @Pointy ok I will edit my heading, please don't label it negatively my point is already low. thans.

Comment: I have not applied negative labeling.

Comment: You can use the spread syntax? Like `[...nodeList1, ...nodeList2]`.

Comment: @trincot I will definitely check this out, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine both into an array with the spread syntax:

```
const both = [...this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("input"),
              ...this.shadowRoot.querySelector("slot[name='fields_toFill']").assignedNodes()];
```